# How to check if Controller already exists when already configured route using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, routes

On my website, I am loading the content dynamically from database like this

```
e.g mysite.com/about-us
```

for this, there is an enrtry in database, so it will load the content for 'about-us' & print it using "page" controller only.

for this what I have done is, I have added below configuration in routes.php

```
$route[':any'] = "page";
```

but lets say if I already have controller named "about-us" and I want to load that & not the one from database, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smooth solution would be to use the error/missing_page controller and point it in the `config/routes.php`.

Then it would automaticly pick all existing controllers first, and then that controller.

You can also call `show_404()` if you don't find a record in the database.

This allows you to create new controllers without having to point all of them in the route file.

[Read about 404 override here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: awsome, that was quick solution

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this

```
$route['about-us'] = "aboutus";
$route['about-us/(:any)'] = "aboutus/$1";
```

before

```
$route[':any'] = "page";
```

as the CI route is not greedy, it will not check for the page controller after it finds the about-us controller.